# Clion + Cmake Test CMake run finished with errors

Tags: windows, gcc, cmake, g++, clion

I find same problem like this link:[CLion + MinGW Test CMake run finished with errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48241152/clion-mingw-test-cmake-run-finished-with-errors)
But it couldn't solve my problem,I try its answer but couldn't work!

I'm new on this IDE, and programming on Windows, I've installed MinGW and added to enviroment path all is ok, I can compile and execute code from "cmd", but when I run CLion I have this error:

> D:\JetBrains\CLion\bin\cmake\win\x64\bin\cmake.exe
> -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=D:/mingw64/bin/mingw32-make.exe -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=D:/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=D:/mingw64/bin/g++.exe -G "CodeBlocks - MinGW Makefiles" -S D:\xwb\sad -B D:\xwb\sad\cmake-build-debug
> -- The C compiler identification is GNU 8.1.0
> -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
> -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
> -- Check for working C compiler: D:/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe - skipped
> -- Detecting C compile features
> -- Detecting C compile features - done
> -- Configuring done
> -- Generating done CMake Warning:   Manually-specified variables were not used by the project:
>
> ```
> CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER
> ```
>
> -- Build files have been written to: D:/xwb/sad/cmake-build-debug [Finished]

This is the photo.
[image]

Comment: Isn't the error message - "The CMAKE_C_COMPILER is set to a C++ compiler" - self-explanatory? You assigned a C++ compiler to be a C one (and vice versa).

Comment: Sorry,but I try to use right path also worry!